# Iterating over an enum class: it works, but is it conforming the standard?

Tags: c++, loops, enums

In the c++ code below+output, the following is used to iterate over the values of an enum class, say MyEnumClass: (the enum class has contiguous values)

```
for (const auto& e : MyEnumClass() )
{
  // ...
}
```

In order for the range-based for-loop to work, I had to define the operators ++ and *, as well as begin(MyEnumClass) and end(MyEnumClass).

Although this works, I have not been able to find if it is a legitimate approach. Is it according to the C++ standard? The operators and begin/end I understand, but what is really the meaning here of MyEnumClass()?

I hope there is somebody who can shed some light on this.

Regards,
Bertwim

```
#include <iostream>

enum class MyEnumClass : int
{
   BEGIN,

   ONE=BEGIN, TWO, THREE, FOUR, // consecutive values!

   END
};

auto begin( MyEnumClass )
{
   return MyEnumClass::BEGIN;
}

auto end( MyEnumClass )
{
   return MyEnumClass::END;
}

MyEnumClass operator++( MyEnumClass& p )
{
   return p = static_cast<MyEnumClass>( static_cast<unsigned>( p ) + 1 );
}

MyEnumClass operator*( MyEnumClass p )
{
   return p;
}


int main( int, char*[] )
{
   for (const auto& e : MyEnumClass() )
   {
      std::cout << static_cast<int>( e ) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Compilation and run: (compiler is gcc 11.3.0)
[519] cpptest> g++ main.cpp && ./a.out
0
1
2
3

Comment: It's a legitimate approach.  Rather than `static_cast<unsigned>` I'd use [std::to_underlying](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying).  I'd probably also put in sanity checks and throw std::logic_error if the bounds are exceeded somehow, but I'm paranoid... I program in C++.

Comment: `MyEnumClass()` yields a zero-initialized value of type `MyEnumClass`, i.e. `static_cast<MyEnumClass>(0)`. Of course your approach only works, if there are nono "gaps" in the integral values of the enum constants.

Comment: This is legal and clever, but looks ugly. Imagine someone accidentally applying `*` to a enum value, or passing some meaningful enum value into ranged-for (something other than `MyEnumClass()`, expecting it to somehow affect the iteration). You shouldn't cram this into the enum itself, make a separate range class.

Comment: Adding `BEGIN` and `END` enumerators will confuse enumerator checks inside `switch` blocks, which are quite useful.

Comment: These are very useful comments. Thanks, all of you. @fabian: thanks for explaining the meaning of MyEnumClass(). After re-reading the cppreference.com I now better understand the range-based for loop.
@

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly fine. You only need to make sure that the additional functions you defined are placed in exactly the same namespace as the enumeration, so that they can be found via argument-dependent lookup.

You also made a minor mistake by using `unsigned` instead of `int` in one of the casts. This mistake can be avoided by replacing the `static_cast`'s with C++23's [`std::to_underlying`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying), which can also easily be implemented before C++23.

Also, using `const auto&` instead of just `auto` in the range-for loop is a bit weird. `operator*` is returning by-value, so the reference will anyway be bound to a temporary, making the reference part potentially misleading.

`MyEnumClass()` in the range-expression of the range-for loop is simply a `MyEnumClass` prvalue which is value-initialized, meaning here zero-initialized, meaning here initialized to `static_cast<MyEnumClass>(0)`, meaning here initialized to `MyEnumClass::BEGIN`. So instead of `MyEnumClass()` you could have written `MyEnumClass::BEGIN`, which actually reads clearer.

The problem with this approach is that the type `MyEnumClass` now represents a single enumeration value as well as a range of enumeration values. That can get confusing quickly. It would be preferable to write a class with proper iterators which specifically represents the enumeration range.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me understanding the range_based for this construct.  
It is a bit of a shame, I think that in C++ this type of iteration is not made simpler. Maybe in the future...